# DB2: Query Memberfile of a Table with SQL

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I want to qry a member of a DB2 Table - I am not the owner of the Database.
When I am running this:

```
SELECT * FROM LXXXXX.X99(MBR1)
```

I get that token "()" is not valid.

How should i do that?

Comment: This may help: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/accessing-files-multiple-members-using-sql

Comment: @bvstone you should write up the main info there as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 SQL

```
CREATE ALIAS MYLIB.MYMBR2_ALIAS FOR MYLIB.MYFILE (MBR2)
select * from mylib.mymbr2_alias
drop alias mylib.mymb2_alias
```

or mix of cl and sql you can override to the member before starting sql

```
OVRDBF FILE(Z1)          
       TOFILE(QTEMP/Z1)  
       MBR(X1)           

select * from z1

dltovr z1
```

Comment: I work with the use of ALIAS - works perfect - thank you!